# MS Excel 2007 VBA Macro to insert three row where the value of the cell changes

Tags: vba, excel

I copied below vba code from a forum to insert new rows where the value of the cell is different from above. It works perfect but it only inserts 1 new row.

I need to insert THREE new rows. Please help with some code please.

**VBA**

```
Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue() 

    Dim lRow As Long 

    For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 
    If Cells(lRow, "L") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "L") 
        Then Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert 
    Next 

    lRow 

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the code with us please?

Comment: this is the code {Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue() 
    Dim lRow As Long 
    For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1 
        If Cells(lRow, "L") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "L") Then Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert 
    Next lRow 
End Sub 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub InsertRowAtChangeInValue()

    Dim lRow As Long

    For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(lRow, "L") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "L") Then _
            Range(Rows(lRow), Rows(lRow + 2)).EntireRow.Insert
    Next lRow

End Sub
```